# malloc in caller, free in callee

Tags: c, malloc

Is it good practice to malloc in the caller function, and then free in the callee function?

Example:

```
int main() {

    int *ptr = malloc(100);
    foo(ptr);
    return 0;
}

void foo(int *ptr) {
    free(ptr);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2998167

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13442375

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/2wu0i5/is_it_better_to_malloc_inside_a_function_or/

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thks for the links, but I am more interested in free, rather than malloc. In the example given, should I free it in main() or free it in foo()?

Comment: Well, if the function you're calling is responsible for malloc'ing, then it should either free the memory itself or return a pointer to the memory so allocated.

Comment: Ergo, it seems to me that the decision to be made is not where to free the memory (since that seems self-evident), but rather where to allocate it.

Comment: Add mentioned, it's fine, but not always the best approach. If it's hard to determine the required lifetime (e.g. asynchronous task), I'd add some kind of optional callback you can pass, which would then take cleanup responsibility.

Answer (score 5):

It is valid C code to call `malloc` in `main` and `free` in `foo`, but it is not considered best practice.

If allocation and deallocation are done in different, unrelated, functions, then it becomes that much harder to tell if every block of memory obtained from `malloc` is actually freed (to prove you don't have a memory leak) or to prove that every pointer passed to `free` actually comes from `malloc` (which is a requirement for using free).

Answer (score 1):

In your specific context? I'd ask why you could not simply pass `int` down by value...

But lets assume you are passing some complicated `struct bar`, that has the property of not being a nice stack resident... That's absolutely fine... Just ensure that the function `foo(bar*)` is clearly marked as taking responsibility for `bar` and that it will fulfil that responsibility by calling `free(bar)` later.

That last part is important as many applications have more than just `malloc`/`free` memory management. Often you will also have memory mapped files, system heaps, perhaps even specialised allocators.

Why this is important is that passing a `Bar*` obtained from a memory mapped file to `foo(bar*)` is actually illegal, as it is illegal to pass it to `free(bar*)`. On some systems this will be ok, nothing bad happens (because you are lucky). On other systems prepare for debugging woes... poor, poor soul.

The important question here is not: Is this good practice? But: Have I ensured each piece of memory is being appropriately managed?

*As an aside, to illustrate that your question holds its own answer, I would like to challenge you to use free(...) without passing it a pointer...*